# How to use layers in Android

Tags: java, android, layer

So I have this project in android I'm developing, and right now I have an image of a body diagram. It includes the heart, stomach, intestine, esophagus, kidneys, liver, and appendix.

Basically, I just want to be able to click only on THAT part of the image, (ie. Clicking on the heart) to update the textview I have to say "Heart."

I downloaded Paint.NET and using the magic wand, I'm able to select a certain part of the body like the heart or stomach. Do I need to create layers in Paint.NET or is this possible in Android using canvas?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can mark off specific drawing regions with just Canvas. You'll want to create [Paths](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) for each of the anatomical pieces, and create your canvas from there.

Comment: So does this mean that I have to recreate the entire drawing using canvas? The regions would be somewhat difficult to work with, since the shapes in the drawing that I want to use are bumpy and odd-shaped. Would this be the only option?

Comment: I believe so -- it's a one-time thing though, so it's not that terrible. You might want to search around for some software that converts selections to (x,y) delimited line segments. If you need to do this often, then you might be better off writing that software yourself!